# Strange sudden reboot, followed by a beep on startup

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I built a Hackintosh a few months ago, using a H97m Pro4 ASRock board, 16gb of RAM and an i5 4690k cpu (two 8GB RAM sticks).

Yesterday while working on my PC, it suddenly rebooted. Then I chose verbose mode to see if something was going on. I got a kernel panic which went too fast and I wasn't able to capture a picture of it. Then I got the next reboot, after which I got a single beep sound. ([Beep Sound](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t2k6m8q7i6b9jx/Asrock%20Beep.m4a?dl=0))

As soon as I pressed the power button, I'd hear the beep sound immediately, followed by a reboot. After the reboot, the HDD would start spinning and then I'd get the beep, and then it would reboot. So it basically alternated between beeping as soon as it started powering up, and hdd spin followed by the beep and reboot. (I remember this problem had happened once again some time earlier, but at that time it happened when I moved the tower of my PC while using it.)

So I thought of removing the video card first, and the problem persisted. Next I removed one of the RAM sticks, and then I got 4 beeps. So I removed the RAM stick and inserted the other stick, and once again I got 4 beeps (4 beeps I believe is for memory error but I'm not sure). After the 4 beeps the CPU fan would keep spinning with nothing being showed on screen. Placed both sticks and it started up, no errors, nothing, it booted fine. (Strange, huh?)

I inserted the video card and no problems anymore. I memtest-ed the RAM memory and no errors were found. Also I couldn't find any panic log.

Also, I noticed that the mouse and keyboard were not working. So I inserted them into another port, and the mouse started working, but the keyboard still wasn't working. I swapped the ports of mouse and keyboard and they both started working. I also want to add that sometimes when I left my USB 3.0 portable HDD plugged into the USB port, and the PC was shut down, if I removed the HDD it would sometimes start up the PC.

I know this is a lot but I wanted to provide as much background as I could. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [asrock beep codes](http://www.asrock.com/support/qa/TSDQA-01.pdf), 1 short Memory refresh timer error, 4 short System timer failure

Comment: hmm, could it be something about RAM frequency?

Comment: No idea, I just threw the link out for you to chew on ;)